# I can't see any in[] and out[] in my notebook

Tags: input

I can open my notebook but when i write, for example, x+2 = 5 I can't see on the left any " in[]= " and when i click enter the notebook doesn't show me anything (i can't see the " Out[]= ".

Comment: Under the option "Palettes", then "Writting Assistant", then under Writing and Formatting / Notebook properties and actions go to "Content" and select "Cell Labels: Show/Hide". I think with that you should be able to see again the In[] and Out[] 's in your notebook.

Comment: nope, i can see "in[]" and "out[]" but after i have written all my stuff. What i wolud like to see is shown in this video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfXRTCpDZkc&list=PLCTMeyjMKRkqd7NLq7hKZw7Cb3pd0ejVW. As you can see on the left appear "In[]=" and "Out[]=" after he has written something

Comment: also a can't see resoults like this "ArrayPlot[{{1, 0, 0, 0.3}, {1, 1, 0, 0.3}, {1, 0, 1, 0.7}}]". I write it but when I click enter appear nothing

Comment: are you pressing enter only, or shift+enter?

Comment: i just press enter

Comment: I have tried with shift+enter and it works ! Thank you ! ( it's the first time that I use Mathematca and I don't konw a lot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try "Shift+enter".

One single "Enter" just mean a new line in Mathematica notebook, but "Shift+Enter" means run the code you input in the cell.